# Make a "LEFT UNION" query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several databases (`nobu` and `bu`) with exact same tables (one is just a back up of the other).
I need  to get values from a table from both databases to join them with other tables then I obviously use an `UNION`. The thing is, some products have different names in the tables from both `bu` and `nobu`.
I then tried to select only one database about this table (I used `nobu` since it's the latest one), but I noticed that some products are not in `nobu`, but are actually in `bu` (which makes it not a backup anymore).

The part of the query in which I need this looks like this :

*With this I get duplicates*

```
... INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM nobu.dbo.product UNION SELECT * FROM bu.dbo.product) AS product
ON [...] INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM nobu.dbo.name UNION SELECT bu.dbo.name) AS name
ON product.key = name.id ...
```

*With this I get some of the products with `NULL` name since it doesn't exist on `nobu`*

```
... INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM nobu.dbo.product UNION SELECT * FROM bu.dbo.product) AS product
ON [...] INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM nobu.dbo.name) AS name
ON product.key = name.id ...
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to perform a `LEFT UNION` or something like that, to get all the values from `nobu`, and if there is no data, take the ones from `bu`, without getting the duplicates (since they can have different names on both databases).

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` keyword in your sub query for the parameters you want to retrieve unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If only names have been changed and suggesting that table names is not a big table and will not create performance issues then this code below will do the job:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM nobu.dbo.product UNION SELECT * FROM bu.dbo.product) AS product
ON [...] INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM nobu.dbo.name UNION SELECT bu.dbo.name WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM nobu.dbo.name)) AS name
ON product.key = name.id
```

Comment: I have been trying to do this for days now .. Thank you for your help it is exactly what I needed !! And about performance issues, my table `name` is pretty huge (5000+ entries and 30+ columns), what do you suggest to increase performance ?

Comment: Using `IN` keyword is not recommended for large data, instead use `GROUP BY`

Comment: Grouping by is an option, but you should decide which function to use for name, min, max or what and this will give you name from each table in case of duplicate and based on request it was to get form table A and only what is missing from table B. In this situation only the solution above will works.

Comment: @shukrigashi Yep you're right : I tried with `GROUP BY` but still returned duplicates when entry exists on both databases. Thanks again for your solution :)